# CNN based copy move forgery localisation

Tags: localization, conv-neural-network

i am trying to make a forgery detection model using deep learning that basically detects  a type of forgery called copy move forgery and so far I've build a (binary)CNN model that detects wether an image is forged or not but I am kinda stuck now like I am trying to find out the region that's forged,can someone please help I am very new to this.

Comment: This question is too vague and broad - You need to ask about a more specific issue, providing code examples where appropriate, as well as what you've tried to solve the problem already. This will make it possible for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file as plain text and finding 'file identifiers' like Title, Subject, Tags, Comments, Program name and Copyright etc.

or

also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

This is a list of file signatures, data used to identify or verify the content of a file. Such signatures are also known as magic numbers or Magic Bytes.

A google search for 'file identifiers wiki' gives alternate keywords searches such as 'file format', 'list of file signatures', 'file format examples', 'how to find file signature', 'file signature database', 'file magic number list'.